# Perl file exists test fails when path contains spaces

Tags: perl, if-statement, exists

Below is an example of what I am talking about

```
$PathPlusFileName gets set in Gtk2 File Chooser dialog SUB

if (-e $PathPlusFileName) {
    print "found file\n";
} else {
    print "did not find file\n";
}
```

IF block works as long as there are no spaces in the PATH name.
Did try double quoting the path, didn't help.
Any suggestions on how to correct would be appreciated.

Comment: I am sure this is not a problem with Perl itself. It could easily be a problem with Gtk2. Please show a minimal, complete and verifiable example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: In a (now-deleted) comment you wrote that the path is `//mnt/backup/Backup_1.0/2017-09-19_Dell_140g\ Deb9.1_MATE_Desktop/20170919_swap2.000`, i.e. has a backslash before the space. Is the backslash literally part of the file name, or is it used to escape the space? The `-e` operator doesn't require you to escape the file name.

Answer (score 3):

It works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'name with spaces'; 
open ( my $testfile, '>', $filename ) or warn $!;

if ( -e "name with spaces" ) { 
   print "\"$filename\" exists\n";
}
```

I suspect you'll find something else is going wrong. My first guess would be - did you remember to `chomp` your input? But we can't answer without seeing how this value is set.

Comment: Yep it chomp was used on resulting the path

Comment: But what _is_ the resulting path? Have you tried printing it to see what's being passed?

Answer (score 0):

As it turn out, the previous programmer that work on the package GUI section had left this line of test code active.
    $PathPlusFileName =~ s/ /\ /g;
One it was removed, if(-e worked as expected. Thank all for the help and suggestions!

Answer (score -1):

Just put your variable in quotes:

```
if (-e "$PathPlusFileName")
```

Comment: Perl is not shell. Perl does not have a comparable word-expansion feature. Therefore, putting a variable into quotes doesn't actually do anything here. (This would only make a difference in case the variable held an object with operator-overloading magic, likely not the case here.)

Comment: My bad, you're right, should have tested it before replying!